# Inserting data into Postgres database with dart

Tags: postgresql, dart, crud

I have a postgres database, containing a table called "users". The table has four fields:

- id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
- display_name TEXT NOT NULL,
- email TEXT NOT NULL
- phone_number TEXT

I would like to add data to it from a dart code.
My attempt looked like this:

```
import "dart:io";
import "package:postgres/postgres.dart";
void main() async{
  var connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
        "localhost", 5432, "test",
        username: "something", password: "notTellingYou");
    try {
      await connection.open();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    "display_name": "foo",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com"
  };
  await setData(connection, "users", data);
  
}

Future<void> setData(PostgreSQLConnection connection, String table, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  await connection.query("""
    INSERT INTO $table(${data.keys})
    VALUES ${data.values};
  """);
}
```

The problem is that I get an exception

> (PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42601: syntax error at or near "display_name" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use variable substitution:

```
import "dart:io";
import "package:postgres/postgres.dart";

Future<void> main() async {
  final connection = PostgreSQLConnection("localhost", 5432, "test",
      username: "something", password: "notTellingYou");
  await connection.open();

  final data = <String, dynamic>{
    "display_name": "foo",
    "email": "foo@gmail.com"
  };
  await setData(connection, "users", data);
  await connection.close();
}

Future<void> setData(PostgreSQLConnection connection, String table,
    Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  await connection.execute(
      'INSERT INTO $table (${data.keys.join(', ')}) VALUES (${data.keys.map((k) => '@$k').join(', ')})',
      substitutionValues: data);
}
```

The generated text will here be: `"INSERT INTO users (display_name, email) VALUES (@display_name, @email)"` and each variable (beginning with `@`) will be automatically replaced by the value for each key inside your map.

This will also ensure correct escaping of special characters in your values.